# sscanf multi string scan

Tags: c, scanf

i want to capture following string in c with sscanf

```
"1=Salam Khobi|FC93F8A120F491F3A8=Rial|F191FEA4"
```

but sscanf only fills `&customInput.type` and `customInputTitle[0]` with "Salam Khobi" and other part of string would not scan.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum {
    INPUT_NUMBER = 0,
    INPUT_NORMAL = 1,
    INPUT_PASSWORD = 2,
    INPUT_PAYAMOUNT = 3,
} inputType;

typedef struct {
    char * title[2];
    char * extra[2];
    inputType type;
    unsigned minLen:6;
    unsigned maxLen:6;
    unsigned forceLen:1;
    unsigned editable:1;
    unsigned char data[100];
} lcdInput;
#define CUSTOM_INPUT_LENGTH     40
static unsigned char customInputTitle[2][CUSTOM_INPUT_LENGTH];
static unsigned char customInputExtra[2][CUSTOM_INPUT_LENGTH];
const char * payload = "1=Salam Khobi|FC93F8A120F491F3A8=Rial|F191FEA4";
#define CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX       "%d=%[^|]s|%[^=]s=%[^|]s|%s"
static lcdInput customInput = {
        .title = {&customInputTitle[0], &customInputTitle[1]},
        .extra = {&customInputExtra[0], &customInputExtra[1]},
        .type = INPUT_NORMAL,
        .editable = 1,
        .forceLen = 0,
};

int main()
{
    memset(&customInputTitle, 0, CUSTOM_INPUT_LENGTH << 1);
    memset(&customInputExtra, 0, CUSTOM_INPUT_LENGTH << 1);

    sscanf(payload, CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX,
           &customInput.type,
           &customInputTitle[0], &customInputTitle[1],
           &customInputExtra[0], &customInputExtra[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that works. i thought `[` and `]` are options which comes between `%s` for scanning strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"%d=%[^|]|%[^=]=%[^|]|%s"` is the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem Asked About

After a `|` character is encountered with the scanset directive `%[^|]`, `sscanf()` will resume matching with the `|` character. The next directive should be a literal `|` to avoid a matching failure. In the original code, with `%[^|]s`, the `s` is *not* a part of the scanset directive, and instead `sscanf()` seeks to match a literal `s` in the input. Also, note that maximum width specifiers should always be used with the `%s` and `%[]` `fscanf()` family directives to avoid buffer overflow with malicious or malformed inputs:

```
"%d=%39[^|]|%39[^=]=%39[^|]|%39s"
```

### Some Other Serious Issues

Always enable warnings when compiling C code; doing so here would have helped you avoid several serious problems. There are a lot of warnings for this code, and most of the problems listed below lead to undefined behavior. I always use at least `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`, and I have added a sample of gcc output for the original code at the end of the answer.

The posted code is missing `#include <string.h>` for `memset()`.

The `.title` and `.extra` fields of `lcdInput` should be `unsigned char *`, since these point to the first elements of `unsigned char` arrays.

In the initialization of `customInput` the `&` operators should be removed. `customInput.title` and `customInput.extra` are both expecting pointers to `unsigned char` (or `char`s before the above correction). With, e.g. `&customInputTitle[0]` you have a pointer to an array of `CUSTOM_INPUT_LENGTH` `unsigned char`s (or `char`s before the above correction); this is a type mismatch, and your compiler should complain vociferously (with warnings enabled). Instead, just use:

```
static lcdInput customInput = {
    .title = {customInputTitle[0], customInputTitle[1]},
    .extra = {customInputExtra[0], customInputExtra[1]},
    .type = INPUT_NORMAL,
    .editable = 1,
    .forceLen = 0,
};
```

Here, `customInputTitle[0]` is an array of `CUSTOM_INPUT_LENGTH` `unsigned char`s, which will decay to a pointer to its first element (`unsigned char *`). Alternatively, you could use `&customInputTitle[0][0]`, `&customInputTitle[1][0]`, etc.

Similarly, you need to remove the ampersands from the `customInput` arrays in the call to `sscanf()`. Here you also need to do something about `&customInput.type`. This is an `enum` type, and you can't input an `enum` value. Again, the compiler complains with warnings enabled. Instead, try:

```
int typeInput;
if (sscanf(payload, CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX,
           &typeInput,
           customInputTitle[0], customInputTitle[1],
           customInputExtra[0], customInputExtra[1]) == 5) {
    if (typeInput >= INPUT_NUMBER && typeInput <= INPUT_PAYAMOUNT) {
        customInput.type = typeInput;
    } else {
        /* Handle error */
    }
};
```

Here `typeInput` is used to collect input, the value returned by `sscanf()` is checked to verify that the correct number of values was assigned, and the value of `typeInput` is checked against the value range for `inputType`. If input is as expected, `typeInput` is assigned to `customInput.type`.

The calls to `memset()` will work, but why obfuscate things with bitshifts? You don't need the `&` operators here, either, but in this case they are OK. Instead, consider:

```
memset(customInputTitle, 0, sizeof customInputTitle);
memset(customInputExtra, 0, sizeof customInputExtra);
```

Here is the corrected code. This compiles with no warnings using `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>        // missing header

typedef enum {
    INPUT_NUMBER = 0,
    INPUT_NORMAL = 1,
    INPUT_PASSWORD = 2,
    INPUT_PAYAMOUNT = 3,
} inputType;

typedef struct {
    unsigned char * title[2];    // need unsigned char
    unsigned char * extra[2];
    inputType type;
    unsigned minLen:6;
    unsigned maxLen:6;
    unsigned forceLen:1;
    unsigned editable:1;
    unsigned char data[100];
} lcdInput;

#define CUSTOM_INPUT_LENGTH     40

static unsigned char customInputTitle[2][CUSTOM_INPUT_LENGTH];
static unsigned char customInputExtra[2][CUSTOM_INPUT_LENGTH];
const char * payload = "1=Salam Khobi|FC93F8A120F491F3A8=Rial|F191FEA4";

// bad format string
#define CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX       "%d=%39[^|]|%39[^=]=%39[^|]|%39s"

// & operator not needed
static lcdInput customInput = {
    .title = {customInputTitle[0], customInputTitle[1]},
    .extra = {customInputExtra[0], customInputExtra[1]},
    .type = INPUT_NORMAL,
    .editable = 1,
    .forceLen = 0,
};

int main(void)
{
    // could use improvements
    memset(customInputTitle, 0, sizeof customInputTitle);
    memset(customInputExtra, 0, sizeof customInputExtra);

    // & operators not needed
    int typeInput;
    if (sscanf(payload, CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX,
               &typeInput,
               customInputTitle[0], customInputTitle[1],
               customInputExtra[0], customInputExtra[1]) == 5) {
        if (typeInput >= INPUT_NUMBER && typeInput <= INPUT_PAYAMOUNT) {
            customInput.type = typeInput;
        } else {
            /* Handle error */
        }
    };

    return 0;
}
```

### GCC Output with Warnings

Here are the compiler warnings with `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` from the original program posted in the question:

```
bad_program.c:27:19: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         .title = {&customInputTitle[0], &customInputTitle[1]},
                   ^
bad_program.c:27:19: note: (near initialization for ‘customInput.title[0]’)
bad_program.c:27:41: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         .title = {&customInputTitle[0], &customInputTitle[1]},
                                         ^
bad_program.c:27:41: note: (near initialization for ‘customInput.title[1]’)
bad_program.c:28:19: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         .extra = {&customInputExtra[0], &customInputExtra[1]},
                   ^
bad_program.c:28:19: note: (near initialization for ‘customInput.extra[0]’)
bad_program.c:28:41: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         .extra = {&customInputExtra[0], &customInputExtra[1]},
                                         ^
bad_program.c:28:41: note: (near initialization for ‘customInput.extra[1]’)
bad_program.c: In function ‘main’:
bad_program.c:36:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘memset’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     memset(&customInputTitle, 0, CUSTOM_INPUT_LENGTH << 1);
     ^~~~~~
bad_program.c:36:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memset’
bad_program.c:36:5: note: include ‘<string.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘memset’
bad_program.c:25:33: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘inputType * {aka enum <anonymous> *}’ [-Wformat=]
 #define CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX       "%d=%[^|]s|%[^=]s=%[^|]s|%s"
                                 ^
bad_program.c:39:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX’
     sscanf(payload, CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
bad_program.c:25:33: warning: format ‘%[^|’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 4 has type ‘unsigned char (*)[40]’ [-Wformat=]
 #define CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX       "%d=%[^|]s|%[^=]s=%[^|]s|%s"
                                 ^
bad_program.c:39:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX’
     sscanf(payload, CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
bad_program.c:25:33: warning: format ‘%[^=’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 5 has type ‘unsigned char (*)[40]’ [-Wformat=]
 #define CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX       "%d=%[^|]s|%[^=]s=%[^|]s|%s"
                                 ^
bad_program.c:39:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX’
     sscanf(payload, CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
bad_program.c:25:33: warning: format ‘%[^|’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 6 has type ‘unsigned char (*)[40]’ [-Wformat=]
 #define CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX       "%d=%[^|]s|%[^=]s=%[^|]s|%s"
                                 ^
bad_program.c:39:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX’
     sscanf(payload, CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
bad_program.c:25:33: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 7 has type ‘unsigned char (*)[40]’ [-Wformat=]
 #define CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX       "%d=%[^|]s|%[^=]s=%[^|]s|%s"
                                 ^
bad_program.c:39:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX’
     sscanf(payload, CUSTOM_INPUT_REGX,
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```